# How to make JBoss EAP LDAP login module set the ldap uid attribute as the Principal name

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ldap, jboss7.x

I have set up a security domain in JBoss EAP 7.1 to authenticate users using JEE declarative security:

```
<security-domain name="mutuaLdap" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://xxx:389"/>
            <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
            <module-option name="bindDN" value="xxx"/>
            <module-option name="bindCredential" value="xxx"/>
            <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="dc=xxx,dc=com"/>
            <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
            <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(&amp;(cn=%v)(objectclass=groupofuniquenames))"/>
            <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
            <module-option name="defaultRole" value="user"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

In my application I use a login form where the user passes his credentials. The LDAP login is working as expected ignoring the uid case from the user input, the problem though is that **I need the Principal to use the exact value from the uid attribute of the user LDAP entry**, e.g:

1. User login form: someUser
2. LDAP user: uid="SOMEUSER",ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx
3. JBoss is setting the Principal.name value to whatever the user used in the login form -> someUser but I need SOMEUSER

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement this functionality you must create a custom login module.